# What is Origin URL when making HttpRequests from Visual Studio Unit Tests?

Tags: security, visual-studio-2017, httprequest, access-control, allowed-origin

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to run an integration test (TestMethod) to make read requests to a service.

The issue is that the service has [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) security implemented, meaning that it only allows the requests if the sender's url (i.e. origin) is specified/recognized by the service.

**Question**

> How can i find out what the origin url when running unit tests from
>   Visual Studio?

Comment: I think `Origin` is not set in those requests. Also you should not use the `Origin` or `Referer` headers for authorization, because an attacker can send any value, including the ones accepted. The purpose of the same origin policy from this point of view is mostly to prevent CSRF, not access control.

Comment: The origin header is just one of many security checks that we do. It's not for authorization as you've mentioned.